# insert html summernote shows up as text

Tags: grails, summernote

I'm trying to insert html code into summernote field. I'm using grails 2.3.11 and I'm sending plain html from database

`$("#summernote").summernote("code", "${text}");`

Expected output is [image]

But what I get is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on grails side. I had to use `${raw(text)}`